# ASP.NET Web API HMAC Authentication Encryption On Client Side

Tags: asp.net, encryption, hmac

I am creating an asp.net API and I intend  on using HMAC authentication to validate incoming requests.

Each user will have public and secret key. The secret key is used to add encrypted value of public key in query string named signature and public key also in query string.

When an user makes a request I am encrypting the supplied public key in the query string with the secret key I am getting from the database on server side.

If there is a supplied signature in the query string that matches my encrypted string then I am allowing user to access the API, otherwise I send an unauthorized request error.

However my problem is when calling the web API method using jQuery, the secret key is visible on client side because I am using CryptoJS to encrypt the public key.

So I have to move encryption logic to server side. Best way to avoid secret key on client side JavaScript?

Comment: although HMAC can be used for authentication it's used for integrity in most cases. Also, saving secret keys in the client side makes them "public", since everyone has access to your client side code. If your API uses encryption you might have to ask for user authentication, so a token based exchange might help. Check how facebook oauth works for example.

Comment: @bitoiu thanks for suggestion. i have one web form application and i am creating separate project for web api to expose some functionality of that web application to registered user only. i don't want implement another form based authentication in web api project. so is there any way i can authenticate user form my web application. does oauth works in my scenario?